# iOS: cocoa Pods: How do I add a new dependency to an existing pod?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have juuuust started with Cocoa Pods.

I have this workspace now after initially experimenting and getting AFNetworking successfully connected via [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12139/introduction-to-cocoapods).

[image]

I want to now add in more dependencies like core-plot specifically.
I found [this link to a 'PodSpec' of Core-Plot](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/commit/fb2808a1c0fc5ac23e1a5e85e02039f40bde75fa)

Problem is, I have no idea how to further implement this...
Anyone have a quick run-down of what to mod and what commands in terminal to run?

Comment: DO I just add this * pod'CorePlot', '~> 1.4' * to the Podfile and recompile?

Comment: Exactly only that is needed

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to add the pod in Podfile and do pod install from terminal that's it. The steps can be summarized as

1. In terminal change the directory to your project directory containing *.xcodeproj
2. Run **open Podfile**. Which opens the Podfile in textEdit.
3. Add  **pod'CorePlot', '~> 1.4'** to it and save.
4. Run **pod install** -- **NOTE* that is **pod update** if already installed.

You are good to go.

Comment: ok great so I did that and it appears to have installed by the following:    BeausMacPro:maryruns beaudamore$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.26.2 is available.

Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (0.9.1)
Installing CorePlot (1.4)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
... etc but now I am getting an error inside Pods-CorePlot @ sizeWithTextStyle saying:   
assigning to 'CGSize' (aka 'struct CGSize') from incompatible type 'id' ... that inside THEIR cocoapod... and I missing a dependency or something?

Comment: @Beau I'm sorry don't have much experience with Core-Plot.

Comment: @Anupdas **NOTE* that is **pod update if already installed.** what do you mean ?

Comment: @entropy It means to run `pod install` or `pod update` depending conditions.

Comment: Using: open -a Xcode Podfile opens the podfile in Xcode instead of text editor. Sometimes text editor can use more visually appealing quotes which can confuse Cocoapods. Something to bear in mind if things aren't working

Comment: @weesplodge Nice point, one needs to disable smart quotes in `TextEdit`

Comment: NB: *no need to restart XCode or reopen any of its windows*, though you may need to recompile your project before XCode will recognize the `import` statement of the newly installed pod.

Answer (score 11):

After you have initially installed CocoaPods into your project, you can add new dependencies (or remove unused ones) by editing the Podfile. Then simply run pod install again.

If you use AppCode it has nice integrated support, so that it can update Pods for you, just edit the Podfile in AppCode, and it will suggest for you to add the new dependencies.

[image: Pods-AppCode]

**Edit:**

In fact, run `pod install` again after adding new pods, [not update](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html).

Comment: Bingo. I appreciate it. I had figured that out via endless searching previously, but your answer is correct and deserves the up vote. P.S. sorry I didn't respond sooner, I've been up against deadlines.

Answer (score 6):

Simply run below command

```
pod update
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to ur project folder and open terminal and set the project source to the terminal

```
-> Run open Podfile. Which opens the Podfile in textEdit.
-> Add pod'CorePlot', '~> 1.4' to it and save.
-> Run pod install -- NOTE(if u want to update all podfile then run pod update)
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI: as per [this link in google groups, 1.4 may be the problem in cocoa pods](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreplot-discuss/UPw9PBfBMAc)

I tried:

```
pod 'CorePlot', '1.3'
```

and it compiles... it must be a problem with 1.4 and cocoa pods

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of any pod noobs like me.

To update a pod file in Xcode project.

First close xCode.

open terminal

type

```
 sudo gem
```

Then when prompted enter your systems password

Next cd into the directory where you have your project and the podfile.

> note* if your folder name has special characters like an "&" type the
>   first part and press the Tab key. Terminal will auto complete and escape the special characters for you :-)

Once inside your project folder where you have the podfile

type

```
 pod update
```

Thats it. Wait for terminal to finish and voila.

> Additional tips for terminal noobs
>
> To list the files in a folder type ls
>
> To re-enter a previous command use the up down arrow on your keyboard